# Swinject inject self's property into new UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, swinject

Let's pretend we have an `UITableViewController` that on `didSelectRowAtSection` loads an instance of a class named i.e.: `ClassToInject` and it wants to inject it through a property injection because our `ViewControllerToBePushed` has a property of `ClassToInject`, that subsequently (because it's an `UITabBarViewController`) on the `didSet` callback it searches for all its `viewControllers` property that conforms to `ClassToInjectPresentable` simple as:

```
protocol ClassToInjectPresentable { 
  var property: ClassToInject { get set } 
}
```

Until now, i would just do something like this:

```
func didSelectRowAtIndexPath {
     let classToInject = self.loadClassToInjectFor(indexPath)
     let tabBarViewController = SomeTabBarViewController()
     tabBarViewController.property = classToInject
     self.navigationController.push(tabBarViewController, animated: true)
}
```

And in `SomeTabBarViewController` ...

```
class SomeTabBarViewController: ClassToInjectPresentable {
  var property: ClassToInject? {
  didSet(newValue) {
      self.viewControllers.filter{ $0 is ClassToInjectPresentable }.map{ $0 as! ClassToInjectPresentable }.forEach{ $0.property = newValue }
  }
 }
```

And everything should be get loaded nice and easy (but it's not). I've read about `Swinject` and this might be solved with it. I have seen lots of examples registering things like:

```
container.register(Animal.self) { _ in Cat(name: "Mimi") }
```

But I don't know if I can register some property that is loaded in `self`:

```
container.register(ClassToInjectInjector.self) { _ in 
self.loadClassToInjectFor(indexPath) }
// And then
container.register(ClassToInjectPresentable.self) { _ in 
SomeTabBarViewController() }
    .initCompleted { r, p in
        let tabBar = p as! SomeTabBarViewController
        tabBar.property = r.resolve(ClassToInjectInjector.self)
        // And lastly?
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the final answer by following the suggestions proposed.

```
public class Containers {
    fileprivate init() { }
}

extension Containers {
    static let activityPresentableContainer: Container = {
        let container = Container()
        container.register(ActivityTabBarController.self) { (r: Resolver, arg1: Activity) in
            return ActivityTabBarController(activity: arg1)
        }
        container.register(ActivityPresentable.self) {
           (r: Resolver, arg1: ActivityPresentableTabs, arg2: Activity) in
           switch arg1 {
           case .summary:
               return ActivitySummaryViewController(activity: arg2)
           case .detail:
               return ActivityDetailPageViewController(activity: arg2)
           case .map:
               return ActivityMapViewController(activity: arg2)
           case .charts:
               return ActivityChartsViewController(activity: arg2)
           case .strava:
              return ActivityStravaViewController(activity: arg2)
           }
        }.inObjectScope(.transient)
       return container
    }()
```

With this approach, the named `ActivityTabBarController` gets instantiated always by the `activityPresentableContainer` using the following statement:

```
let controller = Containers.activityPresentableContainer.resolve(
    ActivityTabBarController.self, argument: activity
)!
```

And then, each of the tabs inside the TabBarController gets instantiated using the required argument `Activity` and the type of tab itself using a `.transient` context. It resolves like this:

```
let activitySummary = Containers.activityPresentableContainer.resolve(
   ActivityPresentable.self, arguments: ActivityPresentableTabs.summary, activity!
) as! UIViewController
```

This way I can generalize the tabs of the tab bar depending just on the information that they're using. If one of the tabs change in any moment, I can just change the registration, following the `ActivityPresentable` protocol.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to recommend proper solution without knowing details of your application, but here are some suggestions:

```
container.register(ClassToInjectInjector.self) { _ in 
    self.loadClassToInjectFor(indexPath) 
}
```

In general, all `register`-ations should be done outside of your objects. Common setup ishaving  one global `Container`, which contains all the registrations - you should look at them as instructions to build application objects without any implicit context. If your dependency needs to be created in the `UITableViewController`, you can pass it to `resolve` method as an argument:

```
container.register(ClassToInjectPresentable.self) { resolver, property in
    let tabBar = SomeTabBarViewController()
    tabBar.property = property
    return tabBar
}

// in UItableVIewController
container.resolve(ClassToInjectPresentable.self, 
                  argument: self.loadClassToInjectFor(indexPath))
```

Also this is usually a bad idea:

```
.initCompleted { r, p in
    ...
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
 }
```

You should not mix application logic with DI - use Swinject purely for constructing your dependencies.

So your `UITableViewController` might look something like this:

```
func didSelectRowAtIndexPath {
    let classToInject = self.loadClassToInjectFor(indexPath)
    let tabBar = container.resolve(
        SomeTabBarViewController.self, argument: loadClassToInjectFor(indexPath)
    )
    navigationController.push(tabBar, animated: true)
}
```

As for your `TabBar` and its view controllers: how do the `UIViewControllers` get into `TabBar`? Is it possible to do something like this?

```
class SomeTabBarViewController {
    init(viewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        ...
    }   
}

container.register(SomeTabBarViewController.self) { r, property
    SomeTabBarViewController(viewControllers:[
        r.resolve(MyViewController.self, argument: property),
        r.resolve(MyViewController2.self, argument: property)
    ])
}
```

Comment: where does `tabBar.property = injector` come from?

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to be `tabBar.property = property`. I've updated an answer